# Removing duplicates string array c++

Tags: c++

I would like to read from a file containing one column of strings, i.e.

```
AAAA
BBBB
22
4556
.
.
.
```

and rewrite in the same file only the unique elements.

```
    sprintf(nameID,"Try.dat");
    IDFile = fopen (nameID,"r+");
    std::vector<std::string> test; 
    fputs (test,IDFile)
    std::sort(test);
    auto it = std::unique(std::begin(test), std::end(test));
    test.erase(it, test.end());

    for(int k = 0; k<test.size();k++){
        fprintf (IDFile,"%s \n",test[k].c_str());
    }
    fclose (IDFile);
```

But I get the following errors

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int fputs(const char*, FILE*)’

error: no matching function for call to ‘sort(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&)’

warning: ‘auto’ changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]

error: ‘it’ does not name a type
```

Any help/better way of doing it ?

thanks

Comment: Strange c/c++ mix :-/ ...

Comment: which compiler are you using?

Comment: Please don't mix C & C++. Also, probably you need to revisit [_fputs_](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputs)

Comment: fputs require string to be c style string not string class object. You can try for test.c_str() at first parameter on fputs call statment

Comment: you've lost a semicolon after `fputs`, forgot to name a type of the IDFile variable, and many more... And it is a normal learning process. Just keep going. But you shouldn't post to SO every time you see a compiler error. Otherwise you will learn nothing.

Comment: You need to read in a vector of strings, Which part of your code is supposed to do that?

Answer (score 3):

The standard library is your friend:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::set<std::string> set;

  for (std::string line; getline(std::cin, line);)
    set.insert(line);

  for (auto const& s : set)
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```